# Keycloak - how to connect with application

Tags: java, spring, keycloak

How can I link a user from keycloak to an existing application? I have done authentication via keycloak and JWT, I have Student and Teacher entities and how will the application know that the one who logged in is for example Student with id 1 and has some list of subjects assigned. What do I need to implement? How to make registration of new users?

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarify - you have user 'Student1' in Keycloak with id guid1 (guid1 is keycloak's internal id for that user, not database or any other kind of object), you are successfully authenticated with that user, and now you want to 'map' that user to entity in your database (or just application level) like Student? That means you should store in a 'Students' table keycloak's user id like that:
[StudentId, Name, LastName, UserId]
where UserId is id from Keycloak for that user.
Registering new users should be done in two steps:

1. creating user in Keycloak thought the adapter or REST API (I don't know which one you'd prefer).
2. creating a record in the table 'Students'.

All business-domain stuff you are doing with students entities like in any other application.

Comment: student/teacher is a role (maybe group), so why not to use Keycloak's roles/groups concept?

Comment: I guess it's not. Some business logic may be coupled to it. If there is no other purpose except defining user's roles, keycloak roles can be used.

Comment: IDP (Keycloak) provides identity and user details (e.g. assigned user roles/groups) usually - so IDP is single place where user permissions are managed. Then app uses those details and performs authorization based on those details. I don't see a problem with any business logic.